# Was the Trippies show a commentary on modern children's entertainment?

Tags: when-the-tripods-came

In the prequel When The Tripods Came, humans are first hypnotized and brought under control via those who watch the Trippies cartoon. In The City of Gold and Lead, Will's Master explains that they had initially gained control via television signals, so the idea has long been established already. But John Christopher deliberately created a bright and saccharine sweet cartoon series that drew in the children and many adults and allowed them to be brainwashed.

Was this just an idea he had for how it worked, or was this deliberate commentary on the state of television and specifically children's entertainment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Christopher (Pseudonym of Sam Youd) was a British Army Signalman during the Second World War so he would have been familiar with the power of radio and television signals.

As with many in his generation, he may well have regarded television as a propaganda tool and idiotic distraction (cf Roald Dahl) and his prolific science fiction and other writing demonstrates an enthusiasm for literature and he regularly returns to themes of disaster, self-sufficiency, self-discipline and resistance to authority both benevolent and oppressive.

'The Lotus Caves' (1969) has the main theme as 'the development of a young person's will and independence, and the conflict between benevolent authority and individual conscience.' (Wikipedia)

Since 'When the Tripods Came' was written after the original book and the TV adaptation - which had only two seasons and did not conclude the story and included changes which Christopher/Youd disapproved of - the introduction of an all female family to provide love-interests (interview on wordcandy.net) it is conceivable that he had little love for modern British Children's TV - by the 80's it featured a lot of cartoons, American imports and toy brand tie ins.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I'll accept it, but could you share the link for that interview? I grew up reading the books (and his other works) and watching the series and I'd love to read it.

Comment: Sure. I can't find the actual interview (looks like it was correspondence) - but the essay it's referenced in is here: http://www.wordcandy.net/2006-05-11-the-white-mountains-by-john-christopher